# htaccess redirecting issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

#### My current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/kohana/, use /kohana/
RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]


</IfModule>
```

When someone navigates to:

> http://mysite.com/demo/test

I want them to go to the actual folder. When someone navigates to:

> http://mysite.com/demo
> I want them to go to index.php/$1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule should work as it is only applied if the requested URL can not be mapped to an existing file (`!-f`) and not to an existing folder (`!-d`). So if `/demo/test` is an actual folder, the second condition (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`) should fail. And if `/demo` is requested and is neither an existing regular file nor an existing folder it should be redirected to `/index.php/demo`.

Comment: To make demo/test a folder, I obviously have to make a folder called demo and create a folder test in it.

Comment: @Alec Smart: Yes, `-f` and `-d` cause a real filesystem lookup.